Why did SSh stop working with webhost after upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. Web host connection fails on 2 different machines
I recently upgraded my web development computer to Ubuntu 24.04 and now I can't ssh in to my web host at all.
After trying a new password and new ssh key, fiddling with serverAliveInterval connectionAliveInterval and really finding no other posts that seemed to solve the problem, I reinstalled 22.04 and still have the problem.
Looking at verbose output, it's not clear, but I thought host is  accepting the SSH key and it is accepting the password.
Unfortunately, I don't control the web host.
Please let me know what, if you would like to look at anything else.
Here is the verbose output from a recent attempt to log in

    ssh -v alias
    OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
    debug1: Reading configuration data /home/lucky/.ssh/config
    debug1: /home/lucky/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for a2
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to webhost [###.#.##.##] port 7822.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/lucky/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
    debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
    debug1: Authenticating to webhost:7822 as 'userName'
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/lucky/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-128@openssh.com compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-128@openssh.com compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
    debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:wcoWSc8VXzSRHRyLTdyzM8UY+qFON91gHBjMzjEOvUA
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/lucky/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: Host '[webhost]:7822' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/lucky/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
    debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
    debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
    debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Ojg06NqtGvIJVI+mfheuMhnYObn1bXYBzc4DhnXsmps agent
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ed25519 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_xmss 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_dsa 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
    debug1: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible
    No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
    debug1: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible
    No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Ojg06NqtGvIJVI+mfheuMhnYObn1bXYBzc4DhnXsmps agent
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/lucky/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    userName@webhost's password: 
    Authenticated to webhost ([###.#.##.##]:7822) using "password".
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: pledge: filesystem
    client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe


I noticed that include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files.
I don't know if fixing that will correct the problem or how to fix that.

    ls -ls /etc/ssh/
    total 548
      4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    142 Nov  8 10:28 known_hosts
    496 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 505426 Jun 26 06:11 moduli
      4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1650 Feb 25  2022 ssh_config
      4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Feb 25  2022 ssh_config.d
      4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3257 Nov  7 16:56 sshd_config
      4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 26 06:11 sshd_config.d
      4 -r--r--r-- 1 root root   3254 Nov  7 11:10 sshd_config.original
      4 -rw------- 1 root root    525 Nov  7 11:08 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
      4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    187 Nov  7 11:08 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
      4 -rw------- 1 root root    419 Nov  7 11:08 ssh_host_ed25519_key
      4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    107 Nov  7 11:08 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
      4 -rw------- 1 root root   2610 Nov  7 11:08 ssh_host_rsa_key
      4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    579 Nov  7 11:08 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
      4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    342 Dec  7  2020 ssh_import_id

Obviously, /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d exits as does known_hosts

    ls -l .ssh/
    total 16
    -rw------- 1 lucky lucky  221 Jun  7 11:27 config
    -rw------- 1 lucky lucky 3434 Nov  7 15:45 id_rsa
    -rw-r--r-- 1 lucky lucky  752 Nov  7 15:45 id_rsa.pub
    -rw-r--r-- 1 lucky lucky  142 Nov  7 11:23 known_hosts


Here is the relevant parts of .ssh/config

    cat .ssh/config 
    Host webHostAlias
      HostName webHost 
      Port 7822
      User userName
      
    
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa,ssh-dss


This is output from ssh logs

    journalctl -fu ssh
    Nov 07 17:03:12 lucky-Precision-3551 sshd[18495]: Server listening on :: port 22.
    Nov 07 17:03:12 lucky-Precision-3551 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
    Nov 08 08:56:03 lucky-Precision-3551 sshd[18495]: Received signal 15; terminating.
    Nov 08 08:56:03 lucky-Precision-3551 systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
    Nov 08 08:56:03 lucky-Precision-3551 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Deactivated successfully.
    Nov 08 08:56:03 lucky-Precision-3551 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
    Nov 08 08:56:03 lucky-Precision-3551 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
    Nov 08 08:56:03 lucky-Precision-3551 sshd[164509]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
    Nov 08 08:56:03 lucky-Precision-3551 sshd[164509]: Server listening on :: port 22.
    Nov 08 08:56:03 lucky-Precision-3551 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.


I suspect it's some conflict between created by Upgrading and I only know enough to do a complete wipe, either of ssh or the disk.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Looks more like a server side issue than a client side issue. I suggest giving the web host a reboot.

I should have mentioned that I don't control the web host.

After I posted this on Ask Ubuntu, I sent a link to it my web host and they solved the problem. It was on their end.

Please delete the question and the answer, as the problem was not related to Ubuntu and it won't help anyone else.
